# stuck with PyQt5 import error in python 3.6 32bit

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I already used python 3.6 and anaconda
currently i download python3.6 32bit, my os is win7, 64bit though, for kinda neededs

I checked py3.6 32bit download successfully to next step i try to install PyQt5 from cmd like "pip install PyQt5", check it as well it done. But it can't import in python32(i try to code from cmd by admin's author) with following error:

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'"
```

I thought it cause a wrong path. So i directly redownload it(PyQt5) on web into python32 lib directory but no joy after that, I don't know why the issue still exist

what can i catch this matter?

please don't answer redownload all you need, existing has lots settings and libraries,

any suggestion for me?

Comment: You likely have pip using a different Python installation that your default Python interpreter. Try running `python3 -m pip install PyQt5 --user` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: sincerely thanks a lot

Comment: If that was the actual answer to your question, I can write it as an answer so you can close the question. Glad to help in any way possible.

Answer (score 1):

Get the appropriate (32-bit or 64-bit) installer from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.5.1/. During the installation it will complain about not finding Python 3.5, just ignore the error. When it asks you for installation directory, point to your Python 3.6 folder and install it. I tried this on my PC with Python 3.6 32-bit and the following script ran fine:

```
import sys
import PyQt5
print("hello")
```